# Installing Packages

Tags: ros, packages, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying to learn ros3djs web interfacing. In the tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/ros3djs/Tutorials/VisualizingInteractiveMarkers), it was written to install the following packages: [interactive_marker_tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/interactive_marker_tutorials), [interactive_marker_proxy](http://wiki.ros.org/interactive_marker_proxy), [rosbridge_server](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_server), [tf2_web_republisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_web_republisher).

How do i install them ?
(I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo)

Thanks and regards !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251027/installing-packages/) by [Werewolf_86](https://answers.ros.org/users/28918/werewolf_86/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2016-12-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For most released ros packages you can install them via apt-get.

The signature is in general:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<your distro>-<meta package name with underscores (_) replaced by dashes (-) >
```

So for instance for your first package interactive_marker_tutorials the package wiki tells you that it is hosted inside the metapackage visualization_tutorials (http://wiki.ros.org/visualization_tutorials) . visualization_tutorials  is released so we can install it via apt-get. For your distro indigo the command would then be:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-visualization-tutorials
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2016-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-31**:
Note that you can install individual packages also using `apt-get`. No need to install the entire metapackage.

**Comment by [Werewolf_86](https://answers.ros.org/users/28918/werewolf_86/) on 2016-12-31**:
Thank you !